# Creating remote transactions and attaching statements in MarkLogic

Tags: transactions, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to implement functionality similar to MarkLogic REST API's `/transactions` endpoint in a custom API. However, it looks like only some of the functions needed achieve this are available in XQuery.

`xdmp:transaction-commit()` and `xdmp:transaction-rollback()` are provided to remotely manage existing open transactions, but there are no corresponding XQuery functions to open a new transaction or to attach new statements to it.

I snooped around in the REST API implementation to see how it's done there, and they use the undocumented function `xdmp:transaction-create()` with the deprecated option `<transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>` (I tested with the `<update>` and `<commit>` options, which segfaults the server!).

Statements are then attached to a transaction in the XML rewriter via `<set-transaction>`, which doesn't correspond to an XQuery function, but I assume it's the same thing as using `eval` or `invoke` with the`<transaction-id>` option (also deprecated).

A simple proof of concept using these methods seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if I'm missing a way to do this without using undocumented and deprecated features. Maybe it's okay because that's how REST API does it? It just seems odd to provide functions to commit and roll back remote transactions for which there is no approved way to create or update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the only way to achieve that yourself and create your own API is by using undocumented functions.

Take a look at [Multi-statement Transactions](https://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/multi-statement-transactions) in XQRS with [transaction.xq](https://github.com/cfoster/xqrs/blob/master/optional-libraries/transaction.xq), this may give you a better idea still.

As for setting whether individual statements are read-only or updating, you can use the %xdmp:update annotation.

Comment: I noticed that this manages transactions using only the transaction ID, always defaulting to the host ID associated with the request. Is there any concern that if subsequent requests for a transaction don't stick to the same host, it might not find the transaction?

Comment: Potentially yes, in which case - one could modify the code to first find the host which held the transaction. However, keeping things simple - If you're gonna' do multi-statement transactions, it's probably best to deal with the same host for the duration of that transaction, especially as the design here over HTTP is using a Session Cookie to track the Transaction which is associated with a particular host anyway.
Also important to mention, if you find a bug with XQRS and create an issue on GitHub - it will be fixed.